# Get part of result of command line in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I would like to use the following command line to get the current Wi-Fi channel.

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I
```

I would like to use exactly this command, because it's possible that I'm using more parts of the result.
So I'm needing an AppleScript that returns me only the current Wi-Fi channel of the command.

I'm thankful for any help.
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example In AppleScript using tron_jones's answer.

The result of the command is set to `_channel` and then used in a dialog box just to show the result.  Obviously `_channel` can be used in a variety of ways.

```
set _channel to do shell script "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I | grep 'channel:' | awk '{print $2}'"
display dialog "Wi-Fi is using Channel: " & _channel
```

Note: The fully qualified pathname for `grep` and or `awk` may need to be supplied.  Also the double-quotes around `grep "channel:"` were replaced with single-quotes so the command could be incapsulated in double-quotes in order to compile due to the single-quotes in the `awk` command.

By the way, the command can be reduced to the following using asterisks (`*`) to shorten the written path to the `airport` command:

```
set _channel to do shell script "/S*/L*/P*/A*/V*/C*/R*/airport -I | grep 'channel:' | awk '{print $2}'"
```

To shorten the command line further, thanks to bmike, in a Terminal use the following command to create the symlink:

```
sudo ln -s "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport" "/usr/local/bin/airport"
```

Then, as an example in Terminal, all you need to do is type: `airport -I`

Or in an AppleScript command using the previous example:

```
set _channel to do shell script "airport -I | grep 'channel:' | awk '{print $2}'"
```

Comment: For what is the `$2`?

Comment: It is the second field of the input record to `awk`.  `.../airport -I | grep "channel:"` outputs `channel: 11` and pipes it to `awk` and it prints "`11`" as it's `$2`.  If you said  `awk '{print $1}'` the result would have been "`channel:`".

Comment: Thank you for your extensively reply. It works and was/is very helpful. :)

Comment: Maybe you can help me in this also: How can I create from the full result a list in AppleScript? With `as list`  I'm getting an error. I think the problem is that there are no commas before a return.

Comment: @user121028 One question per question - also asking a new one in comments is considered very poor form. It makes one look a little bit like a "help vampire" although you're not showing any signs of that malady other than asking it in comments.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using the "[grep](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html)" and "[awk](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/awk.1.html)" commands from bash.  You can use them to parse the data given in bash.  Here is example using the details you described above.

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I | grep "channel" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Do yourself a favor and sym link the binary to /usr/local/bin so you can just type airport (or script it)

```
airport -I | grep "channel" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Where can I change to `/user/local/bin`? With a new Terminal window it doesn't work.

Comment: @user121028, In a Terminal, use the following command to create the symlink: `sudo ln -s "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport" "/usr/local/bin/airport"` Then, as an  example, all you need to do is type: `airport -I`

Comment: Why would you use `grep` and `awk`?  `airport -I | awk '/channel/{print $2}'`